# Sufficient condition for a differentiable function constant

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f = u+iv$ complex differentiable in a ball centered at $(0,0)$ and $au^2+bv^2$ is  constant where not both $a$ and $b$ zero. Then prove that $f$ is constant.

If $a=0$ or $b =0$ I have finished the proof. But I am not able to prove for case bith $a$ and $b$ not zero and is $(0, 0)$ required in problem. e.g. it is not required in case $a=b=1$.

Mathematical Analysis Apostol exercise 5.37

Comment: Have you tried to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Yes but didn't get answer. And can't write here what I have done because i don't know latex

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $au^2 + bv^2$ is identically zero, then $u = v = 0$, so $f = 0$. Now suppose $au^2 + bv^2 = c$, a nonzero constant. Differentiating with respect to $x$ and $y$ gives $$auu_x + bvv_x = 0$$ and $$auu_y + bvv_y = 0$$ Since $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$, the second equation can be written $-auv_x + bvu_x = 0$. Therefore

$$0 = (-auv_x + bvu_x)^2 + (auu_x + bvv_x)^2 = a^2u^2(v_x^2 + u_x^2) + b^2v^2(u_x^2 + v_x^2) = c(u_x^2 + v_x^2).$$

Since $c$ is a nonzero constant, $u_x^2 + v_x^2 = 0$. Therefore $u_x = v_x = 0$. Then $u_y = -v_x = 0$ and $v_y = u_x = 0$. Since $u_x = u_y = 0$, $u$ is constant; since $v_x = v_y = 0$, $v$ is constant. Hence, $f = u + iv$ is constant.